# JupyterHub Connection refused when access using curl

Tags: jupyterhub

I had followed JupyterHub's [QuickStart](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) to successfully install JupyterHub on Linux machine, and start the service by typing

```
jupyterhub
```

and the output suggest that now the server is listening on port 8000:

```
$ jupyterhub
[I 2018-07-02 02:32:25.756 JupyterHub app:1656] Using Authenticator: jupyterhub.auth.PAMAuthenticator-0.9.0
[I 2018-07-02 02:32:25.756 JupyterHub app:1656] Using Spawner: jupyterhub.spawner.LocalProcessSpawner-0.9.0
[I 2018-07-02 02:32:25.759 JupyterHub app:1014] Loading cookie_secret from /home/ec2-user/jupyterhub_cookie_secret
[I 2018-07-02 02:32:25.775 JupyterHub proxy:429] Generating new CONFIGPROXY_AUTH_TOKEN
[W 2018-07-02 02:32:25.776 JupyterHub app:1160] No admin users, admin interface will be unavailable.
[W 2018-07-02 02:32:25.776 JupyterHub app:1161] Add any administrative users to `c.Authenticator.admin_users` in config.
[I 2018-07-02 02:32:25.776 JupyterHub app:1188] Not using whitelist. Any authenticated user will be allowed.
[I 2018-07-02 02:32:25.810 JupyterHub app:1838] Hub API listening on http://127.0.0.1:8081/hub/
[W 2018-07-02 02:32:25.811 JupyterHub proxy:481] Running JupyterHub without SSL.  I hope there is SSL termination happening somewhere else...
[I 2018-07-02 02:32:25.811 JupyterHub proxy:483] Starting proxy @ http://:8000
02:32:26.221 - info: [ConfigProxy] Proxying http://*:8000 to (no default)
02:32:26.223 - info: [ConfigProxy] Proxy API at http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/routes
02:32:26.735 - info: [ConfigProxy] 200 GET /api/routes
[I 2018-07-02 02:32:26.735 JupyterHub proxy:299] Checking routes
[I 2018-07-02 02:32:26.736 JupyterHub proxy:368] Adding default route for Hub: / => http://127.0.0.1:8081
02:32:26.737 - info: [ConfigProxy] Adding route / -> http://127.0.0.1:8081
02:32:26.738 - info: [ConfigProxy] 201 POST /api/routes/
[I 2018-07-02 02:32:26.739 JupyterHub app:1895] JupyterHub is now running at http://:8000
```

But when I try to access to the server by `curl`, it just showed that it's not available.

```
$ curl localhost:8000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8000: Connection refused
```

Did anyone encounter the same problem? Any advice is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

After I made some modification to `jupyterhub_config.py`, it became accessible. And the following is my config:

```
c = get_config()
c.JupyterHub.bind_url = 'http://localhost:8000'
c.JupyterHub.hub_ip='localhost'
```

In order to generate `jupyterhub_config.py` when you first try to config JupyterHub, you can type:

```
jupyterhub --generate-config -f /etc/jupyterhub/jupyterhub_config.py
```

And to start jupyterHub with the file `jupyterhub_config.py`:

```
sudo jupyterhub -f /etc/jupyterhub/jupyterhub_config.py
```